# QGridLayout with PlotWidget-pyqtgraph

Tags: python, pyqtgraph, qgridlayout

I have 3 [`PlotWidget`](http://www.pyqtgraph.org/documentation/widgets/plotwidget.html) (from the `pyqtgraph` library), `obj1`, `obj2` and `obj3`, which I try to insert in a QGridLayout. I want to display all three objects in a single row, but `obj1` must be twice as large as `obj2` and `obj3`.

Thus I wrote:

```
layout.addWIdget(obj1, 0, 0, 1, 2)
layout.addWidget(obj2, 0, 2, 1, 1)
layout.addWidget(obj3, 0, 3, 1, 1)
```

However, visually, `obj1` is much smaller than `obj2` and `obj3` which do have the same size:

```
---------------------------------------------------
| obj1 |     obj2           |         obj3         |
---------------------------------------------------
```

However, if I write:

```
layout.addWIdget(obj1, 0, 0, 1, 1)
layout.addWidget(obj2, 0, 1, 1, 6)
layout.addWidget(obj3, 0, 7, 1, 6)
```

`obj1` appears bigger than `obj2` and `obj3` which are still of the same size, which is the expected behavior:

```
---------------------------------------------------
|          obj1           |    obj2   |    obj3   |
---------------------------------------------------
```

It seems totally contradictory to the doc of [addWidget](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qgridlayout.html#addLayout-2) as my first solution should yield the expected behavior, no?

**EDIT: Piece of code**

```
import pyqtgraph as qtg

obj1 = qtg.PlotWidget()
obj2 = qtg.PlotWidget()
obj3 = qtg.PlotWidget()

layout = QGridLayout()

layout.addWIdget(obj1, 0, 0, 1, 2)
layout.addWidget(obj2, 0, 2, 1, 1)
layout.addWidget(obj3, 0, 3, 1, 1)

box = QGroupBox()
box.setLayout(layout)
self.setCentralWidget(box)
```

Comment: show your code.

Comment: I have edited the first post with what I remember as I do not have the code in front of me.

Comment: If you say it did not work, this may be due to other reasons so put the code that reproduces your error, that is, a [mcve]

Comment: what is `QPlotWidget`?, You could indicate in which part of the docs of pyqtgraph you mention it or how you import it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use void `QGridLayout::addWidget(QWidget* widget, int fromRow, int fromColumn, int rowSpan, int columnSpan, Qt::Alignment alignment = 0)`, rowSpan and columnSpan refers to the other row or another column, and as in your case you have just given a row the rowSpan is not applied, for example if you add a new row you get the following:

```
obj1 = qtg.PlotWidget()
obj2 = qtg.PlotWidget()
obj3 = qtg.PlotWidget()

obj4 = qtg.PlotWidget()
obj5 = qtg.PlotWidget()
obj6 = qtg.PlotWidget()
obj7 = qtg.PlotWidget()

layout = QGridLayout()

layout.addWidget(obj1, 0, 0, 1, 2)
layout.addWidget(obj2, 0, 2, 1, 1)
layout.addWidget(obj3, 0, 3, 1, 1)
layout.addWidget(obj4, 1, 0, 1, 1)
layout.addWidget(obj5, 1, 1, 1, 1)
layout.addWidget(obj6, 1, 2, 1, 1)
layout.addWidget(obj7, 1, 3, 1, 1)

box = QGroupBox(self)
box.setLayout(layout)
self.setCentralWidget(box)
```

[image]

If you need to establish the proportions you must use stretch, in this case `setColumnStretch():`

```
obj1 = qtg.PlotWidget()
obj2 = qtg.PlotWidget()
obj3 = qtg.PlotWidget()

layout = QGridLayout()

layout.addWidget(obj1, 0, 0, 1, 2)
layout.addWidget(obj2, 0, 2, 1, 1)
layout.addWidget(obj3, 0, 3, 1, 1)
layout.setColumnStretch(0, 2)
layout.setColumnStretch(2, 1)
layout.setColumnStretch(3, 1)

box = QGroupBox(self)
box.setLayout(layout)
self.setCentralWidget(box)
```

[image]

The same effect you could get through QHBoxLayout:

```
obj1 = qtg.PlotWidget()
obj2 = qtg.PlotWidget()
obj3 = qtg.PlotWidget()

layout = QHBoxLayout()

layout.addWidget(obj1, stretch=2)
layout.addWidget(obj2, stretch=1)
layout.addWidget(obj3, stretch=1)

box = QGroupBox(self)
box.setLayout(layout)
self.setCentralWidget(box)
```