# QGridLayout different column width

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, qlayout, qgridlayout

I am trying to create a layout looking like this:

```
 _________
|  |      |
|1 |   2  |
|__|______|
|  3 | 4  |
|____|____|
```

Basically, I want cell number 1 the first row to be thinner that cell 2, but cells number 3 and 4 on the second row should have equal widths.

Is it even possible to create a layout like this using QGridLayout in PyQt4?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The task of QGridLayout is to create that type of structure, for this you must use the function:

> **void QGridLayout::addWidget(QWidget * widget, int fromRow, int
> fromColumn, int rowSpan, int columnSpan, Qt::Alignment alignment = 0)**
>
> This is an overloaded function.
>
> This version adds the given widget to the cell grid, spanning multiple
> rows/columns. The cell will start at fromRow, fromColumn spanning
> rowSpan rows and columnSpan columns. The widget will have the given
> alignment.
>
> If rowSpan and/or columnSpan is -1, then the widget will extend to the
> bottom and/or right edge, respectively.

Example:

```
import sys

from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
w = QWidget()
glay = QGridLayout(w)
glay.addWidget(QLabel("1"), 0, 0)
glay.addWidget(QLabel("2"), 0, 1, 1, 3)
glay.addWidget(QLabel("3"), 1, 0, 1, 2)
glay.addWidget(QLabel("4"), 1, 2, 1, 2)

qsrand(QTime.currentTime().msec())

for label in w.findChildren(QLabel):
    color = QColor(qrand() % 256, qrand() % 256, qrand() % 256)
    label.setStyleSheet('.QLabel{{background: rgb({}, {}, {});}}'.format(color.red(), color.green(), color.blue()))

w.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

Comment: Very nice. (even although I couldn't see the snapshot due to company security policy) Out of curiosity: Wouldn't a grid with 3 columns do as well? (I mean: label "2" spans 2 columns, label "4" spans 1 column.)

Comment: According to the diagram provided by the author of the question, it is observed that label 1 must have a lower weight than label 2, label 3 and label 4; label3 has the same weight as label 4, so one solution is that the labels have the following weights: `label1 = 1`, `label2 = 3`, `label3 = 2` and `label4 = 3`

Comment: OK, I see. Hmm. Wasn't there a possibility to use something like weights for layouting? (I remember this roughly as this is _the_ difference to `GtkTable` which I used before I switched to Qt.)

Comment: Qt does not directly implement the weights, another option is to use the strech functions, check my other answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47681774/qgridlayout-with-plotwidget-pyqtgraph